# static linking of opencv for android

Tags: java, android, opencv, static, linker

Please help, I have looked through the documentation for OpenCV static Linking for android [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html) but to no avail. It makes no sense to me, I have no jni folder for my android project and when I try to manually copy the libraries from opencv/sdk/native/libs to my library folder in eclipse It makes absolutely no difference. Also to me it makes no sense when in the documentation it says to use static{ if(!OpenCVLoader.initDebug())} because this makes no difference to my program either. The end result I get is just a black screen that does nothing, or a dialog that asks me to download OpenCV Manager. Thanks in advance to the help.

Comment: Do not call OpenCVLoader.initAsync for static linking. Can you show your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed my problem, It turned out to be a problem with too much work going on in the main thread when I started a new activity.